# IPSec Site-to-site VPN between Cisco ASA 9.0 and StrongSwan 4.4

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

The problem is the ikeV2 authentication with the ASA as initiator.

For the following experimets I set on the ASA the followings PSKs: `local: 123, remote: 321`

---

In case the **ASA is the initiator**:

Now several combinations in `ipsec.secrets` on the StrongSwan side:

***left 123 right 321***

```
ASA:Auth exchange failed

SWAN: tried 1 shared key for '%any' - 'XXX', but MAC mismatched
```

***left 123 right 123***

```
ASA:Failed to authenticate the IKE SA

charon: 11[IKE] authentication of 'a with pre-shared key successful
charon: 11[IKE] authentication of 'b' (myself) with pre-shared key
charon: 11[IKE] IKE_SA x[1] established between b[b]...a[a]
```

***left 321 right 123*** (should be the working one)

```
ASA:Failed to authenticate the IKE SA

charon: 08[IKE] authentication of 'a' with pre-shared key successful
charon: 08[IKE] authentication of 'b' (myself) with pre-shared key
charon: 08[IKE] x[1] established between b[b]...a[a]
```

***left 321 right 321***

```
ASA: Auth exchange failed

SWAN: ... but MAC mismatched
```

***If I set the two PSKs the same on each side then everything works.***

BTW what is the point anyway with IKEv2 having two different PSKs?

Oh, and ASA debugs show the following when it cannot connect:

```
REAL Decrypted packet:Data: 8 bytes
IKEv2-PROTO-5: Parse Notify Payload: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED NOTIFY(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)  Next payload: NONE, reserved: 0x0, length: 8
    Security protocol id: Unknown - 0, spi size: 0, type: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
```

---

Now with **StrongSwan being the initiator**: (ASA still `local: 123, remote: 321`)

***left 123 right 321*** !!!

```
SWAN ok

ASA ok
```

***left 123 right 123***

```
SWAN: received AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notify error

ASA: Failed to authenticate the IKE SA
```

***left 321 right 123***  (should be the working one)

```
SWAN: received AUTHENTICATION_FAILED notify error

ASA: Failed to authenticate the IKE SA
```

***left 321 right 321*** !!!

```
SWAN ok

ASA ok
```

---

Here's the **strongswan conf**

```
# cat /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc

conn TEST
 left=l
 leftsubnet=n/24
 leftid=l
 leftfirewall=yes
 right=r
 rightsubnet=n/24
 rightid=r
 auto=add # or start
 ike=aes256-sha512-modp1024
 esp=aes256-sha1
 keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
```

Here's the **ASA conf**, standard stuff

```
tunnel-group x type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group x general-attributes
 default-group-policy VPN_x_GP
tunnel-group x ipsec-attributes
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key 321
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key 123
group-policy VPN_x_GP internal
group-policy VPN_x_GP attributes
 vpn-filter value ACL_VPN_x
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal IKEv2-ESP-AES256-SHA1
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto map internet_crypto_map 1 match address internet_cryptomap
crypto map internet_crypto_map 1 set pfs
crypto map internet_crypto_map 1 set peer x
crypto map internet_crypto_map 1 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal IKEv2-ESP-AES256-SHA1
crypto map internet_crypto_map interface outside
crypto ikev2 policy 999
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha512
 group 2
 prf sha512
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 1000
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
```

***ipsec.secrets***

```
left : PSK "321"
right : PSK "123"
```

Although I currently suspect that is not entirely correct, I believe it would be for ikev1 but I don't find much documentation for ikev2 (multiple PSKs). For now, I'll investigate in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [discussed on the strongSwan mailing list](https://lists.strongswan.org/pipermail/users/2015-April/007941.html).

As you can see from that thread, in the end it turned out that it makes no real sense to use this, at least not with strongSwan.